# Laravel 5.5 handling failed jobs

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to figure out how to handle failed jobs.  So in my Job class, I basically have something like this

```php
public function handle()
{
    try {
        $someService = new SomeService($);
        $success = $someService->makeApiRequest();

        if($success) {
            //do something
        } else {
            //trigger failed
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->failed($e);
    }
}

public function failed(Exception $exception)
{
    //Log information
}
```

What this is doing is calling a Service class which makes an API request.  This class returns true or false based on whether the API call was successful or not.

At the moment, I just have the API method returning false.  This should mean that the job has failed.  However, the failed function is not called, and as far as Laravel is concerned, the job is processed.

**How can I manually trigger the failed function seeing that I dont have an Exception?**

Thanks

Comment: Are you pushing the job to a queue or running it synchronously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using Jobs, you don't catch the exception. The framework will do this for you and mark the job as failed.

So your `handle` method should just be

```php
public function handle()
{
    $someService = new SomeService($);
    $success = $someService->makeApiRequest();

    if($success) {
       //do something
    } else {
       trow new Exception('error message goes here');
    }
}
```